# Debugging in F# throws AccessViolationException

Tags: debugging, f#

In my F# code I regularly seem to encounter AccessViolationExceptions when stepping through my code;

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in FSharp.Core.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Can anyone shed any light on what might be causing this?

Comment: Waaaaaay too little information. In broad strokes, the exception message is telling you exactly what could cause this: the memory is corrupted. As to _how_ your memory could get corrupted - we need to know _a lot_ more about your program to tell.

Comment: If you could identify a time when the data isn't corrupted you should be able to set a memory breakpoint to detect the point when the data is touched. It's typically not that easy though.